# Laravel Eloquent ORM relationship query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need help, I have a problem with querying Model Relationships.
 I actually know and get the job done using the query method but I'd like to know the "laravel way" of querying relationships.

Here's what's on my controller.
//HealthProfile Controller
//$id value is 2

```
$health_profiles = User::find($id)->with('health_profiles')->first();
```

problem is that the return for the query is the records for id = 1 and not id = 2. It basically ignored the "find" method. I just want to get the health profiles for a specific user_id.

```
[id] => 1
    [firstname] => patrick
    [lastname] => marino
    [email] => patrick@gmail.com
    [membership_code] => starpatrick
    [birthdate] => 1989-05-17
    [contact_number] => 1230123
    [active] => 1
    [created_at] => 2014-07-01 16:10:05
    [updated_at] => 2014-07-01 16:10:05
    [remember_token] => 
    [health_profiles] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [parent_id] => 
                    [name] => patrick star
                    [relationship] => 
                    [gender] => male
                    [birthdate] => 1989-05-17
                    [marital_status] => 
                    [number_of_children] => 
                    [weigth] => 
                    [height] => 
                    [blood_type] => 
                    [blood_pressure] => 
                    [hdl] => 
                    [ldl] => 
                    [vldl] => 
                    [visual_activity] => 
                    [lifestyle] => 
                    [current_bmi] => 
                    [weight_goal] => 
                    [weekly_goal] => 
                    [rdc] => 
                    [created_at] => 2014-07-01 16:10:05
                    [updated_at] => 2014-07-01 16:10:05
                )
```

This is my schema
//User model

```
   public function health_profiles()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('HealthProfile');        
        }
```

//HealthProfile model

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the culprit. L4 has problems with snake cased methods! I changed it to camelCase and it worked.

```
$lawly = User::where('id', '=', 2)->first();
$lawly->healthProfiles->toArray()
```

src: https://coderwall.com/p/xjomzg

Comment: sweet, good looks ... and you dont really need to use the eager loading on a single model so I am glad to see you removed it. :)

Answer (score 4):

First a few words of explanation:

`find($id)` already runs the query (it uses `where(id, $id)->first()` under the hood) so place it at the end, because now you unwittingly did this:

```
User::find($id);
User::with('health_profiles')->first();
```

Another problem is, like you already noticed, that `Eloquent` won't work with this setup:

```
public function health_profiles() ...

$user = User::find($id);
$user->health_profiles; // null
```

because when loading dynamic properties (relations) it looks for camelCased method on the model.

However eager loading **will** work as expected:

```
$user = User::with('health_profiles')->find($id);
$user->health_profiles; // related model/collection
```

So you definitely should comply with the naming conventions if you want `Eloquent` to be your friend ;)

---

**But that's not all. It will work the other way around:**

```
public function healthProfiles() ...

$user = User::find($id);
$user->healthProfiles; // works, returns related model/collection
$user->health_profiles; // works as well, returns the model/collection
```

---

**To sum up and answer your question**, each of those will work for you:

```
// Assuming Profile is the model

// 2 queries
$user = User::find($id);
$profiles = $user->healthProfiles;

// or 1 query
$profiles = Profile::where('user_id', $id)->get();

// or 2 queries: 1 + 1 subquery
$profiles = Profile::whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($id) {
   $q->where('users.id', $id);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting the `with` before the `find` so that the builder knows to eager load that relationship on what you are trying to find.

```
$user = User::with('health_profiles')->find($user_id);
$health_profiles = $user->health_profiles;
```

Comment: thanks! this also works, but I only need the health_profile data, doing this would also return user model data which is an overkill to my method. Thanks!

Comment: if you want i can show you a method of achieving that from the other direction.

Comment: Please do share. Here is my approache      $user = User::where('id', '=', $id)->first(); $user->healthProfiles->toArray();

Comment: if you look at deczo's answer the last example is the other way i was going to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
User::with('health_profiles')->find($id);
```

I don't think you need to call the `first` method because `find` as it's stated will only find the one row of data that you need.

Comment: thanks! this method works too! problem though, is that it also returns the User attributes along with the HealthProfiles, which is too much for what I need.   You're actually right, if you chain first it'll return the wrong User id record.

Comment: Try `$user->healthProfiles`. This will narrow the the returned data up to the health profiles only

Comment: Hey man! that's what I actually did!  anyway how do I filter my healthProfiles to only return records who has "parent_id" = null

Comment: You can try `$user->health_profiles()->where('parent_id', '=', 'null');`